# Is the macOS terminal app open source?

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu

I was wondering the terminal app on macOS is open-source because they use Bash and other open-source software.

Comment: The shell is a different piece of software than the terminal.

Comment: Oh, I thought that because it was used internally that was enough to make it open source. Thanks.

Comment: @Fransebas The terminal in MacOS is software that Apple developed just like the Finder or iPhoto. Whether or not it's open source doesn't depend on whether or not it's internal. The default login shell for MacOS, Bash, is open source as are other shells including zsh, tcsh, and ksh. You can install or compile and run other terminal software that is open source such as iTerm2, Alacritty, and Terminal in MacOS. More information on those terminal applications (and several others) including download links are here: https://www.fossmint.com/alternative-terminal-apps-for-macos/